# Powershell Provider - GetItem Path Error - Custom File as Drive

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-provider

I'm trying to emulate my custom project file as new PS Drive. I am trying to create my custom [Powershell Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is derived from [NavigationCmdletProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.navigationcmdletprovider%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have overridden PSDriveInfo to read and contain the project from the file and filepath is in the root of PSDriveInfo.

I can't override GetItem properly. What I want to do is use `GetNamesFromPath(path, out tableName, out rowNumber)` method. Since my custom project is basically dataset, I would like to use tableName to get the DataTable and rowNumber for ID of DataRow.

The problem is that I get the "path doesn't exist" kind of error. It doesn't event get into the overridden method. Am I missing something to override? The filepath doesn't exist really, but I simply need to handle the path and use WriteItemObject with what I want as object(s) returned, without checking is it valid path.

Edit 1:
One thing I noticed is that it never gets into `GetItem` and therefore into `IsValidPath`. When I debug and use breakpoints, first I load the drive and then `Set-Location` to the drive, `IsItemContainer` is called (it has to be overridden for `Set-Location` to work).

`GetItem` and `IsValidPath` are not called at all, as if it checks for valid path before calling overridden method. Can `NavigationCmdletProvider` work with non-existing paths (except for the file itself), just work with strings that will manually be handled as paths would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you override the `IsValidPath` and `ItemExists` methods:

```
protected override bool IsValidPath(string path)
{
    return true;
}

protected override bool ItemExists(string path)
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I suspected it was something simple I missed. But it didn't solve the problem. I overridden `IsValidPath` method to always return true and changed `GetItem` to always return same table, just to see if it works. Still the same error "Get-Item : Cannot find path 'MyDrive:\myName' because it does not exist.".

One thing I noticed is that it never gets into `GetItem` and therefore  into `IsValidPath`. When I debug and use breakpoints, first I load the drive and then `Set-Location` to the drive, `IsItemContainer` is called. `GetItem` and/or `IsValidPath` are not called.

Comment: I went through a provider I wrote a while ago, try overriding `ItemExists` as well.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't properly overridden, worked only in some cases. I should have seen that, but I got fed up. Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending `NavigationCmdletProvider` then you should override [IsValidPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.itemcmdletprovider.isvalidpath%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ItemExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.itemcmdletprovider.itemexists%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.itemcmdletprovider.getitem%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetChildItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.containercmdletprovider.getchilditems%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and possibly other methods depending on what features you want to support for your PS drives.

The best way to find out which methods are missing implementation is to override all the virtual methods and put a breakpoint in each one. Then execute a cmdlet and see in the debugger what gets called and what are the parameter values.

Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of detailed documentation about implementing custom PowerShell providers. However, you can find a quite detailed tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about this topic with a lot of source code examples. Additionally, you can take a look at the [PowerShell VFS](https://powershellvfs.codeplex.com/) project - it's a wrapper around PowerShell provider API to make it easier to build complicated providers.

Comment: Well, instead of going in step by step as you suggested, I guess I needed to hear from someone else to actually do it. I'm making some progress now, finally. Thank you.